# Selecting last N rows in a single line from the result of a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select a column's last 3 results (rows), separated by ';'.
For example, 
I have a table--> table

```
    ActivityID Ticketnumber Action             ActivityDate
    -----------------------------------------------------------------
    101         45678       abc                10/05/2015 10:00:40 AM
    102         45678       def                10/05/2015 10:05:40 AM
    103         45678       ghi                10/05/2015 10:02:40 AM
    104         45678       jkl                10/05/2015 11:03:40 AM
    105         45678       mno                10/05/2015 12:04:40 AM
```

Here I have distinct ActivityID, and for every TicketNumber an Action is entered at different times. Now I need to select the last three Actions for all the ticketnumbers in the database.
The result should be like:

```
    TicketNumber   Action
    ----------------------------------------------------
    45678          ghi; jkl; mno
```

Note: I need result for all Ticketnumbers in the table. And for some tickets there can be less than three Actions in the database, so in that case only last two or the last action(s) need to be shown.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To get the latest 3 records, use `ROW_NUMBER`. Then use `FOR XML PATH('')` for concatenation:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TicketNumber ORDER BY ActivityID DESC)
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TicketNumber 
    FROM tbl
) t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT '; ' + Action
        FROM Cte
        WHERE 
            TicketNumber = t.TicketNumber
            AND rn <= 3
        ORDER BY rn DESC
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS Action
) x
```

Comment: Great solution, voted it. One tiny hint: You might want to replace the first two characters within `STUFF` as you concatenate with `; `

Comment: Is there an advantage on using the `CROSS APPLY` instead of using directly a subquery in the `SELECT *, (subquery) FROM (...) t`?

Comment: Ah and probably it should be `1, 2, ''`, because the separator has length 2 (`'; '`)

Comment: Perfect solution! Thanks Felix. Is there any way the query could get more optimized in terms of performance? It's taking nearly 12 seconds to process 1 TicketNumber which is too huge!

Comment: @SameepBaxi Is there an index on `TicketNumber`?

Comment: Indexing is not done on any column. Is there any other way? @xanatos

Answer (score 1):

This will probably perform faster:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    ActivityID, 
    Ticketnumber,
    ActivityDate,
    Action,
    row_number() over (partition by ticketnumber order by activityid desc) rn 
  FROM yourtable
  -- if you only want one ticketnumber you add the next line
  -- WHERE TicketNumber = 45678
), Tickets as
(
  SELECT distinct TicketNumber 
  FROM yourtable
  -- if you only want one ticketnumber you add the next line
  -- WHERE TicketNumber = 45678
)
SELECT TicketNumber
    ,STUFF(( 
        SELECT '; ' + [Action] 
        FROM cte t1 
        WHERE t1.TicketNumber = t.TicketNumber
        and rn < 4
        ORDER BY [Action]
        for xml path(''), type 
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') [values] 
FROM Tickets t
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is taking the same amount of time.

Comment: @SameepBaxi Try putting an index on ticketnumber and possibly on activity id

Comment: Indexing is not done on any column. Is there any other way? @ t-clausen.dk